# Não exibe dados na tela Web Api asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Comecei a estudar um pouco de web api usando com asp.net, estou fazendo um exemplo bem simples onde só quero listar os dados da tabela de empregados, mas recebo erro: **No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'text/html'.**

```
    public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static HttpClient WebApiClient = new HttpClient();
    static GlobalVariables()
    {
        WebApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57129/api");
        WebApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        WebApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }
}
```

Controler Index

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<MvcEmpregadosModel> empregadoLista;
        HttpResponseMessage response = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.GetAsync("Empregados").Result;
        empregadoLista = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<MvcEmpregadosModel>>().Result;
        return View(empregadoLista);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o `ReadAsAsync`por `ReadAsStringAsync` :

```
empregadoLista = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync<IEnumerable<MvcEmpregadosModel>>().Result;
```

O método `ReadAsAsync` vai tentar ler algum tipo padrão de `MediaTypeFormatter` como xml ou json mas o media type que esta usando é `'text/html'`.
Como esta usando `'text/html'` você precisa usar o `ReadAsStringAsync` para ler como string.

Comment: obrigado, resolvido